# Need to compose not simple regex

Tags: php, regex

Could you help me please to compose regular expression. I need to find specified symbol (for example +) with all white spaces before and/or after it (minimum one white space must be), if it is not in double or single quotes. And replace it all to another symbol (for example #).

I tried some regex variants like:

```
(("[^"]*"|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|\s*\+\s*
(\s+[+]|[+]\s+)(?=(?:[^"']|"[^"']*")*$)
```

But they don't work correct how i need (

Here is an example of input text:

```
$input_text:
+ Som+e text + asd + 56, 'here + we don't+ replace + ' +45 - "end + here don't replace +" + dfg
+ Som+e text + asd + 56, "here + we don't+ replace + " +45 - 'end + here don't replace +' + dfg
+ Som+e text + asd + 56, "here + we don't '+ ' replace + " - end +
```

// This regex just an example, it needs to be composed that get $output_text example result

```
$output_text = preg_replace('/(\s+[+]|[+]\s+)/', '#', $input_text);
```

And we must get this result:

```
$output_text:
#Som+e text#asd#56, 'here + we don't+ replace + '#45 - "end + here don't replace +"#dfg
#Som+e text#asd#56, "here + we don't+ replace + "#45 - 'end + here don't replace +'#dfg
#Som+e text#asd#56, "here + we don't '+ ' replace + " - end#
```

Comment: How do you define "in double or single quotes" (or rather, how would a regex distinguish between a single quote and an apostrophe as in the first input line)?

Comment: Sorry i make mistake, that i wrote don't in single quotes! And i have already working regex: (("[^"]*"|'[^']*')(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(\s+[+]\s+|\s+[+]|[+]\s+)